# Configure SMS Meitrack

Tags: gps, tracking

How to configure (by SMS) Meitrack in order to stop sending logs when acc is off?

And what is the command used for Meitrack in order to stop/start a vehicle remotely?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you elaborate the question?

Comment: Hello,Sorry for the confusion and misunderstanding. Meitrack should stop sending logs when acc is off, actually i sent sms commands        1)I used 0000,A12,1 the tracker will send logs each 10 sec
Now i need to configure meitrak in order to stop tracking(device should stop sending logs) when acc is off, i tried with A15 but didn’t work.
2) I also need to mobilize/imobilize the vehicle remotly what command should i use.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SMS protocol of the Meitrack trackers (check http://www.meitrack.com/meitrack-support/protocol/MEITRACK_SMS_Protocol.pdf) they support both configuration options.

"Setting Roaming and Track by Time Interval – A55" command can be used in the first case: "Mode 1" differentiates upload intervals when acc. is on and off. Eg, sending 0000,A55,1,1,0 means uploading every 10 sec. when acc. is on, and no upload when acc is off.

"Output Control – C01" can be used to turn on / off outputs of the device remotely, eg. sending 0000,C01,0,12222 opens the first output, while the other 4 remain in their previous state.

It depends on the installation which output is connected to ignition, if any, and also the external battery may be wired directly to the car's battery, and may not turn off when stopping the car. Also the device model should be checked, if these commands are applicable or not (or, if the device has output control slots).